# GET Request with params: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, steam

I am trying to use new features available with Steam API and I am having trouble, I think this is more of general issue than actual service related itself.

I keep getting:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

I am trying to send GET request with parameters using:

```
<?php

    $url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ICSGOTournaments_730/GetTournamentItems/v1?key=".$_SESSION['steam_appid']."&event=9&steamid=".$_SESSION['steam_steamid']."&steamidkey=".$_SESSION['userAuthCode'];
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    echo($response);

?>
```

I am 100% sure the parameters are correct I think it's something rather to do with my code than Steam itself.

When I try to use same code but different API call:

```
$url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ICSGOTournaments_730/GetTournamentLayout/v1?key=".$_SESSION['steam_appid']."&event=9";
```

That executes fine and returns data so it's something related to the other two parameters.

I am wondering is there any problem with the way I am building URL's?

Sessions file (3rd Party):

```
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']) or empty($_SESSION['steam_personaname'])) {
    require 'SteamConfig.php';
    $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$_SESSION['steamid']); 
    $content = json_decode($url, true);
    $_SESSION['steam_appid'] = $steamauth['apikey'];
    $_SESSION['steam_steamid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
    $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['communityvisibilitystate'];
    $_SESSION['steam_profilestate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profilestate'];
    $_SESSION['steam_personaname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
    $_SESSION['steam_lastlogoff'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['lastlogoff'];
    $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];
    $_SESSION['steam_avatar'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
    $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium'];
    $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull'];
    $_SESSION['steam_personastate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personastate'];
    if (isset($content['response']['players'][0]['realname'])) { 
           $_SESSION['steam_realname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['realname'];
       } else {
           $_SESSION['steam_realname'] = "Real name not given";
    }
    $_SESSION['steam_primaryclanid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['primaryclanid'];
    $_SESSION['steam_timecreated'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['timecreated'];
    $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] = time();
    include 'mysql_connection.php';
        $userAuth = getAuth();
        if($userAuth != false){
            $_SESSION['userAuthCode'] = $userAuth;
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['userAuthCode'] = "Unset";
        }
}

$steamprofile['steamid'] = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];
$steamprofile['communityvisibilitystate'] = $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'];
$steamprofile['profilestate'] = $_SESSION['steam_profilestate'];
$steamprofile['personaname'] = $_SESSION['steam_personaname'];
$steamprofile['lastlogoff'] = $_SESSION['steam_lastlogoff'];
$steamprofile['profileurl'] = $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'];
$steamprofile['avatar'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatar'];
$steamprofile['avatarmedium'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'];
$steamprofile['avatarfull'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];
$steamprofile['personastate'] = $_SESSION['steam_personastate'];
$steamprofile['realname'] = $_SESSION['steam_realname'];
$steamprofile['primaryclanid'] = $_SESSION['steam_primaryclanid'];
$steamprofile['timecreated'] = $_SESSION['steam_timecreated'];
$steamprofile['uptodate'] = $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'];
?>
```

Comment: can you post/show the session array?

Comment: Do you have the `php_openssl` extension enabled in `php.ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly well I didn't manually enable it but I just did phpinfo() and it says openSSL Support: Enabled.

Comment: @RavinderReddy added Sessions in question.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` - for using https need use:

from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
When using SSL, Microsoft IIS will violate the protocol by closing the 
connection without sending a close_notify indicator. PHP will report 
this as "SSL: Fatal Protocol Error" when you reach the end of the 
data. To work around this, the value of error_reporting should be 
lowered to a level that does not include warnings. PHP can detect 
buggy IIS server software when you open the stream using the https:// 
wrapper and will suppress the warning. When using fsockopen() to 
create an ssl:// socket, the developer is responsible for detecting 
and suppressing this warning.
```